JavaScript capture data from input field & post it to output field in a multiple row app
I want to input data to a div (column headed 'Result') from an input (columnd headed 'Edit/Update') field using a button (named 'Update') to trigger the event. I can grab the data from the input field and I can identify which button is clicked. I can't seem to combine the 2 functions to get the data transferred from the input to the output div.

This is my code:


// select the parent element
const formGroup = document.getElementById('table');
// select input field
const addData = document.getElementById('input');
// select output field
const output = document.getElementById('output');

// identify which button is clicked
const buttonClicked = (e) => {
  const isButton = e.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON';

  if (!isButton) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(e.target.id);
};
formGroup.addEventListener('click', buttonClicked);

// Get data from input and display to output element
addData.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = addData.res.value.trim();
  if (data.length) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = data;
    addData.reset();
  }
  // console.log(data);
});
<div id="table">
  <div id="title" class="row">
    <div>
      <div class="header">Round #</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="header">Date</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="header">Versus</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="header">Ground</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="header">Result</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="header">Edit/Update</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="line1" class="row">
    <div>
      <div class="header">1.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="header">17/08/2024</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="header">Ipswich</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="header">Portman Road</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="output" class="header"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input id="input" class="data" placeholder="Enter/Edit Result" name="res" />
      <button id="button-1" class="btn btn-success" type="button">
        Update
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="line2" class="row">
    <div>
      <div class="header">2.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="header">25/08/2024</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="header">Brentford</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="header">Anfield</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="output" class="header"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input id="input" class="data" placeholder="Enter/Edit Result" name="res" />
      <button id="button-2" class="btn btn-success" type="button">
        Update
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>




addData.addEventListener('submit' - input fields don't fire submit events, only forms do.

IDs have to be unique, you can't have multiple id="input". document.getElementById('input') will only return the first one. You also have lots of other duplicate IDs in each row. You need to use classes instead of IDs. Then you can use row.querySelector(".output") to find the output element in the current row.
